# VBA Runtime Error 1004 while using a For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a UserForm for Excel and crash-coursing VBA while I do it. I've solved almost all of my issues, but now I'm stuck on this one and none of the existing StackOverflow answers have helped me:

I have a worksheet (Sheet8) which acts as the database the form saves & pulls data from, and I have a listbox (lstIncomeView) that is supposed to populate with values from some of the columns. An example would be:

```
Row 1: Category1 | Category 2 | Etc.
Row 2: Value 1 | Value 2 | Etc.
Row 3: Value 3 | Value 4 | Etc.
```

Where the listbox outputs:

```
Category 1 | Value 1
Category 2 | Value 2
Category Etc | Value Etc
```

And my existing code under UserForm_Initialize()

```
iRow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   
...
'Set IncomeView and ExpenseView lists
Me.lstIncomeView.ColumnCount = 2
iCntI = 0
Me.lstExpenseView.ColumnCount = 2
iCntE = 0
...
GetValues (iRow)
```

with iRow being a public variable, which is altered elsewhere to change which row is currently selected. iCntI and iCntE are also public variables that get manipulated elsewhere for different functions.

Under GetValues, I have the following code which is where the error 1004 throws:

```
Private Sub GetValues(iRef As Integer)
...
Dim iEntryI As Range
For Each iEntryI In Range(Sheet8.Cells(iRef, 14), Sheet8.Cells(iRef, 18))
    If iEntryI > 0 Then
        Me.lstIncomeView.AddItem
        Me.lstIncomeView.List(iCntI, 0) = Sheet8.Cells(0, iEntryI.Column)
        Me.lstIncomeView.List(iCntI, 1) = iEntryI.Value
        iCntI = iCntI + 1
    Else: End If
Next iEntryI
```

Comment: `Sheet8.Cells(0, iEntryI.Column)` - there's no row `0`.

Comment: That was an easy fix. Thanks